# Text for exhibiting different pronunciations

Tags: pronunciation, accent, phonemes, mergers

I'm looking for a text that can be used to showcase various differences in pronunciation across English accents. For example, it could include examples of the various splits/mergers (Mary/merry/mary, fern/fir/fur, cot/caught, etc.), and feature words pronounced differently by, e.g., Canadian, American, and British speakers.

I once saw such a text referenced in a comment to a question here, but, alas, I can no longer find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the text you saw referenced was probably [*Comma Gets a Cure*](http://www.dialectsarchive.com/comma-gets-a-cure). This text has words from all of [John Wells's lexical sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set), which were designed to encompass variation between standard British "Received Pronunciation" and standard "General American," two of the most well-known dialects of English.

Wells's lexical sets don't include the fern/fir/fur distinction however, since both of the source dialects have merged these (they all fall in Wells's NURSE set).